# QuickOSM Critical error

Tags: quickosm

A critical error occurs when launching QuickOSM plugin. See the log below:

```
2024-02-20T12:50:47     CRITICAL    Si è verificato un errore critico, questo è il traceback:
2024-02-20T12:50:47     CRITICAL    
2024-02-20T12:50:47     CRITICAL    base_processing_panel.py
2024-02-20T12:50:47     CRITICAL    Errore: Algoritmo qgis:checkvalidity non trovato
             
2024-02-20T12:50:47     CRITICAL     File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\base_processing_panel.py", line 47, in run
              self._run()
             
              File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 421, in _run
              num_layers = process_quick_query(
             
              File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 318, in process_quick_query
              return process_query(
             
              File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 257, in process_query
              return open_file(
             
              File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 106, in open_file
              layers = osm_parser.processing_parse()
             
              File "[...]/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\parser\osm_parser.py", line 147, in processing_parse
              validity = processing.run(
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.13/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
              return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.13/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 169, in runAlgorithm
              raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
```

Comment: Have you got into contact with the plugin provider? Have you checked their FAQ, bug reports and like?

Answer (score 1):

Go in your QGIS plugin manager and enable "Processing" plugin again.